# Characterization of the least fixed point of a function$\pi$ on $\mathcal{P}(A)$ where $\pi(X) := \{y \in A | (\forall x<y)[x \in X] \}$

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, well-orders, fixed-points

This comes from Notes on Set Theory, 2nd edition.

> Let $\leq$ be a total ordering of a set $A$ and define on the inductive poset $\mathcal{P}(A)$ the mapping
>
> $$\pi(X) := \{y \in A | (\forall x<y)[x \in X] \}.$$
>
> It can be verified that $\pi$ is monotone, and hence has unique strongly least fixed point $A_{\omega}$. Prove that
>
> $$x \in A_{\omega} \iff M_x := \{(s,t) \in A \times A \space | \space s \leq t < x \} \text{ is a well ordering.}$$

By definition of $A_{\omega}$ we know that $A_{\omega}$ is the smallest set $B$ such that $(\forall y < x) [y \in B]$ implies $x \in B$.

I am not sure how to solve this problem. The difficulty here seems to be that $A$ need not be a well ordering (we cannot assume the axiom of choice here). I am not sure if I can prove whether $A_{\omega}$ is well orderable or not; that may make this problem a lot easier. Judging from the chapterthis question came from, it seems like the fact that a family of well ordered sets are well orderable and the property and exitence of Hartog's set may be used to prove this, but I am not sure how to apply those here.

Comment: Every linear ordering has an initial segment which is a well-order. It just might be empty.

Comment: No, the order itself is a subset of $A\times A$. So $M_x$ is just the restriction of $<$ to the initial segment below $x$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila could you give more help to this problem?